# What is DeveloperPayload in Android?

Tags: android

What is `DeveloperPayload String` in Android? I've faced with it in one tutorial which shows how to implement in-app billing in android application:
https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html.

Can someone give me some examples?(2 or more)

How to use it?

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest that you edit your question and provide some context. Where exactly are you seeing this term be used?

Comment: @commonsware I've edited my question.Please, take a look.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is unclear but in android that terminology is generally used in *in-app purchases*.

`developerPayload` is any `string` that you set when user initializes in-app purchase process and when the purchase process finishes successfully, you can call that method of `Purchase` class to check whether the string you did set as `developerPayload` at beginning of purchase process matches `purchase.getDeveloperString()` after successful pruchase or not.

`developerPayload` is used for verification purpose and generally we set user's email address as developPayload but you can set assign anything to that string.

Comment: Does DeveloperPayload String somehow effect on security of my app?

Comment: @S.Drumble4 When you set any string as *developerPayload*, it will be sent to google's server while processing in-app purchase, and when purchase process finishes, server returns that string. Then you can compare server returned string with the string you have set at beginning, if both are same that means there was no security threat affected your process and if both strings are not same then it's a sign that purchase process is affected by any intruder.